# How to assign a string in column 1 as name to a hyperlink in column 2 across all rows in excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have an excel spreadheet that looks like this:

**Input:**

```
Link Name   Hyperlink   Other Data
Group 1     google.de/1     1
Group 1     google.de/2     2
Group 2     google.de/3     3
Group 2     google.de/4     4
Group 3     google.de/5     5
```

I need a VBA sub that assigns all strings in `Link Name` as the name to the link in `Hyperlink`:

**Desired output**:

```
Link Name   Hyperlink   Other Data
Group 1     Group 1         1            # Hyperlink: Underlined, blue
Group 1     Group 1         2            # Hyperlink: Underlined, blue
Group 2     Group 2         3            # Hyperlink: Underlined, blue
Group 2     Group 2         4            # Hyperlink: Underlined, blue
Group 3     Group 3         5            # Hyperlink: Underlined, blue
```

The `Hyperlink` should now be clickable and labeled as defined in `Link Name`. My current approach doesn't seem to loop through the `Link Name` Column:

**Current approach:**

```
Sub rename_links()
For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks   // Select hyperlink
    h.TextToDisplay = _
    Replace(h.TextToDisplay, h.TextToDisplay, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value) 
    Next
End Sub
```

**Current output:**

```
Link Name   Hyperlink   Other Data
Group 1     Link Name           1          
Group 1     Link Name           2           
Group 2     Link Name           3            
Group 2     Link Name           4           
Group 3     Link Name           5
```

I blieve that this is due to `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value` not being affected by `Next`.

**How to assign a string in column 1 as name to a hyperlink in column 2 across all rows in excel VBA?**

Comment: wow, anonymous downvote and close flag after ~10 secs

Comment: I’m not the downvoter but I will (and many others are likely to follow) if you don’t provide your coding efforts

Comment: my apologies, I did not think that this may add value - I have added my  code now

Comment: Why VBA? You can use the formula `=HYPERLINK(A1,B1)` and drag it down?

Comment: VBA is a requirement because this involves python which calls a VBA script at the end of a long pipeline in order to graphically edit the excel-based output

Comment: @sudonym then using VBA to write that formula might be an option

Comment: `Range("D1:D100").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(A1,B1)"` Assuming that you want the links in Col D

Comment: or `Range("D1:D" & LastRow).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(A1,B1)"` You can find the last row using [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

Comment: You can get more help here on adding hyper links in excel: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hyperlinks-add-method-excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple formula in column 2 to achieve this:

```
=HYPERLINK("your link address here", A1)
```

Which uses the text of A1 as link name.

---

Or use VBA to write that formula:

```
Range("B1:B10").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""your link address here"", A1)"
```

Comment: ++ Exactly my thoughts :)

Comment: this works in a static environment. I have accepted the answer. However, an ideal solution does not rely on hardcoded A1 and A2, but IMHO searches for the location of the relevant column names

Comment: @sudonym Well, of course this is only an example showing the relevant technique and no full solution to any *specific* issue. Nevertheless you can only get what you ask for and "*find the relevant column names*" was not part of your question.

Comment: nicely phrased!